# Boolean in a URI query?

Tags: http, url, uri

What is the preferred way to specify boolean value in the query part of URI? A normal query string looks like

```
a=foo&b=bar
```

Say I have a parameter "c" with boolean value, should I state

```
a=foo&b=bar&c=1
```

Or

```
a=foo&b=bar&c=True
```

Or

```
a=foo&b=bar&c=true
```

I checked the query component section of [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) and it does not specify how to express a boolean parameter. So what I want to know is what is the common (or reasonable) way to do it?

Comment: The URI spec (nowadays RFC 3986) simply doesn't care.

Comment: I'd say do whatever's easiest - ie if your in java, Boolean.parseBoolean("true")...

Answer (score 32):

It completely depends on the way you read the query string. All of these that you ask for are valid.

Answer (score 27):

## Use key existence for boolean parameter like `?foo`

For example, use `?foo` instead of `?foo=true`.

I prefer this way because I don't need to waste time to think or trace the source code about whether it should be `true` or `1` or `enable` or `yes` or anything that beyond my imagination.

In the case of case sensitivity, should it be `true` or `True` or `TRUE`?

In the case of term stemming, should it be `enable` or `enabled`?

IMHO, the form of `?foo` is the most elegant way to pass a boolean variable to server because there are only 2 state of it (exist or not exist), which is good for representing a boolean variable.

This is also how Elasticsearch implemented for boolean query parameter, for example:

```
GET _cat/master?v
```

Comment: Sometimes behaviour is different in absence vs false. For instance show all users. Show all users where active = false, show all users where active = true.

Comment: Is there an RFC for this behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately valueless query parameters are not supported by OpenAPI, even though they remove a lot of ambiguity as you say.

Comment: @Tosh but you could set the default value to false when absent

Answer (score 8):

In node with an express server, you can add a boolean parser middleware like [express-query-boolean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-query-boolean).

```
var boolParser = require('express-query-boolean');

// [...] 

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(boolParser());
```

Without

```
// ?a=true&b[c]=false 
console.log(req.query);
// => { a: 'true', b: { c: 'false' } }
```

With

```
// ?a=true&b[c]=false 
console.log(req.query);
// => { a: true, b: { c: false } }
```

Comment: Note that express-query-boolean will recursively parse all parameters and force any "boolean-like" inputs to booleans.

Answer (score 3):

Url are strings and all values in a URL are strings,
all the params will be returned as strings.

it depends on how you interpret it in your code.

for the last one where `c = true`

you can do a `JSON.parse(c)`

which will change it to a boolean.

Also, you have to be careful not to pass it an empty string, if not it will throw an error.

Comment: The question was not about how the parameter itself is read from the url (obviously they are always retrieved as strings) but the best or standard way to write a boolean variable as a parameter.

Comment: Noted, changed my answer,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I managed this with a custom function.

See browser compatibility here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

```js
function parseQuery(url = window.location.search) {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url);
  return Array.from(urlParams.keys()).reduce((acc, key) => {
    const value = urlParams.get(key);
    if (value) {
      switch (value) {
        case 'false': {
          acc[key] = false;
          break;
        }
        case 'true': {
          acc[key] = true;
          break;
        }
        case 'undefined': {
          acc[key] = undefined;
          break;
        }
        case 'null': {
          acc[key] = null;
          break;
        }
        default: {
          acc[key] = value;
        }
      }
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

The function returns an object with all the parsed query parameters and fallback by default to the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this

```
const queryBool = unwrapTextBoolean({{{A_WAY_TO_GET_THAT_TEXT_BOOLEAN}}})
if(queryBool===null) {return;}
if(queryBool){
   /*true-based code*/
}else{
   /*false-based code*/
}
```

---

```
function unwrapTextBoolean(tB){
  if(tB === 'true') return true;
  if(tb === 'false') return false;
  return null;
}
```