# What is the standard way to pass a boolean value through a query string?

Tags: http, url, request, query-string, standards

As far I know, developers use these ways to pass a boolean value through a URL query string:

1. `?value=1`
2. `?value=true` or `?value=TRUE`
3. `?value`

In my opinion, the first one and the second one are misunderstandable if the other side of communication is not aware of the type of value that is expected. With the third is clear because possible values are `the parameter is present` or `the parameter is not present` and this is a binary representation.

But does some recognized kind of standard exist about this?

Comment: There is no standard.

Comment: `true` / `false` is also boolean; how can the second approach lead to any confusion?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Because you want to pass the string valued as true or false.

Comment: I agree with SLaks there is no standard. If it helps, twitter uses #2, for example see the include_entities parameter here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

Comment: See the answer to this same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461668/boolean-in-a-uri-query